# PHP How does it works? Function()->Function()

Tags: php, function

I'm working with `PHP` and I have this expression:

```
$this->ev_info_datos_personales()->set_data($data);
```

I do not understand how it works? which function runs first? If someone could explain it to me, it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend reading any PHP tutorial on object-oriented programming. The functions run left to right because the next function in the chain is called on the return value of the previous function.

Comment: Left to right, usually.